# Regex to match currency value (with decimal 2 digits) but not 0

Tags: regex

I want to match:

```
0.01
0.12
1.00
1.12
12.00
12.34
```

But not:

```
0
0.00
.00
.12
```

To get price value which can not be zero.

I have written this regex:
`/(^\d{1,}\.\d{2}$)|(^\d{1,}$)/`

But it matches:

```
0
0.00
```

which I want to eliminate.

I've also tried with exclusion rules like `^(?!0)(?!0\.00)\d{1,}\.\d{2}|\d+$` but no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to match a value with decimal 2 digits but not 0:

```
^(?![.0]*$)\d+\.\d{2}$
```

The negative [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) checks, if the string does not consist of only `0` and `.`

`\d+\.\d{2}` assures the desired formatting: [One or more](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) digits followed by a `.` followed by 2 digits.

[Test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bJ5jO4/2) (also see explanation on the right side)

---

To also allow `1`, `2.2` change the last part to `\.\d{1,2}` and make it optional:

```
^(?![.0]*$)\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$
```

[Test at regex101.com](http://regex101.com/r/bJ5jO4/4)

Comment: Revoking my accepted answer to this one. This on is nice as @vks stated

Comment: Glad it works for you :) and @vks happy you like it!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex.

```
^(?!0(\.00)?$)\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/dR9cK6/5)

Negative lookahead at the start won't allow `0` or `0.00`

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=.*?[1-9])(^\d+\.\d{2}$)|(?=.*?[1-9])(^\d{1,}$)
```

Try this.Just added `(?=.*?[1-9])` to negate `0`.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yA1jY6/1